# What is the name of a device that would send input current out to my home and maybe upstream from a power device?

Tags: power-supply, power-engineering

Please edit this since I'm too ignorant of electronics and electrical equipment to explain this well.

I'm looking for a device that I can create that would take AC or DC current from a power source and send it into my home and possibly upstream to the power company (if I have a net supply in my home). For instance, if I have a solar panel that produces DC current, what would be the device that I would make that I would want to plug the solar panel into that would then relay the power through my home and possibly to the power company if I have a net supply.

Is there a name for such a device, or names of components I would use for such a device? I would think it would have to be modular e.g. dc/ac conversion, voltage regulator, phase modulation, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such device is called a "Grid tie inverter".
 [Wikipedia - Grid Tie inverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid-tie_inverter)

'Grid tie' means that it is electrically connected to and synchronised with the mains power grid.

"inverter" means that it inputs DC and outputs correct voltage and frequency AC to allow "mains" connection.

---

While people will usually buy a grid-tie inverter "off the shelf" the following PhD thesis design has quite a lot of useful content for this who want to know more about what goes on "under the hood".

[DIY Grid tie inverter](http://www.thebackshed.com/forum/uploads/Dinges/2009-11-05_020350_DIY_grid_tied_inverter_by_Scopeboy.jpg) from a PhD thesis.
 [Chapter on inverter here](http://scopeboy.com/elec/RE/appendix-inverters3_3.pdf)

[Whole thesis](http://scopeboy.com/elec/RE/scthesis.pdf).  PIC based.

[image]

Very DIY :-).
Note use of parallel FETS per phase.
If wishing to learn about such circuits his cCircuit diagram in Fig A6 is worth looking at. The H bridge is driven at two different frequencies to achieve basic 50 Hz polarity control and then high frequency PWM modulation tp generate the sine wave output.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for an [inverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_inverter), and likely a [transfer switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_switch).

Note that selling surplus power back to your utility is far from trivial.  There are contractual issues (not all utilities will pay you for the power), component issues (you need a meter that can handle the buy vs. sell rates), and safety considerations (power generated from the home and sent "upstream" may energize lines that are believed to be safe to touch by service personnel).